# Why Hibernate queries gets stuck in 'idle in transaction' in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, grails

Our Grails app recently has shown signs that it's getting stuck sometimes out of nowhere. There are no exceptions or errors.

But when I check the `pg_stat_activity` I can see some queries there related to stuck process in 'idle in transaction'.

Any clues why this is happening?

I'm using Grails, and Postgres as a database. Those specific query is not a 'for update' lock.

Comment: Grails uses the OpenSessionInView (OSIV) pattern. Therfore the database connection is retrieved from the connection pool when the first sql-statement is requested however the connection is not returned to the pool until the web-request is finished. If your request needs a few ms e.g. because you do some blocking operation afterwards this could cause the observed behaviour.